# How to insert a table on the header

Tags: tables, header-footer, memoir

I am trying to insert a table on the header, just like the example below. The whole document where I was inspired to create this header can be found here [Moshell User Guide](https://www.academia.edu/5520372/Moshell_User_Guide).

[image: Sample of desired output]

On this picture this is header on every page of the document. The pages of course can vary based on the page number.

I have created a sample of code, that can reproduce the table format and also the header with the logo on the left the text in the middle and the page numbering on the right.

Sample of code provided below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[ a4paper , centering ]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % demo option just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum} % demo option just for text
\usepackage{lastpage} % include last page numbering
\usepackage{chngpage} % allows for temporary adjustment of side margins
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY}}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{\includegraphics[height=20pt]{LaTeX_logo}}{\hspace{3cm}Informational\\\hspace{3.1cm} USER GUIDE}{\thepage(\pageref{LastPage})}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{\includegraphics[height=20pt]{LaTeX_logo}}{\hspace{3cm}Informational\\\hspace{3.1cm} USER GUIDE}{\thepage(\pageref{LastPage})}

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}  
    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|} 
      \hline
      \multicolumn{3}{|l}{{\small\textbf{Prepared (subject responsible)}}} & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{{\small\textbf{No.}}} \\
      \multicolumn{3}{|l}{Thanos 1 \& Thanos 2} & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{1553-CXC1328930} \\ \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\small\textbf{Approved (Document responsible)}}} & & \multicolumn{1}{l}{{\small\textbf{Checked}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\small\textbf{Date}}} & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{{\small\textbf{Rev.}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{\small\textbf{Reference}}} \\
      \multicolumn{1}{|l}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{l}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{|l}{\mydate\today} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{J} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Thanos\_UserGuide.tex} \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

I want the header to start from the very first page. Unfortunately on my code the header starts on the second page because of the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables. I am using the [memoir class](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf) because I think it is the most correct to solve my problem but maybe it can be done also by other classes. Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: You need to change the `plain` page style which is used on the first page of chapters. (Or whatever the `memoir` equivalent of `plain` is.)

Comment: I tried this and it did work unfortunately. Thank you for your time and effort to help me though, I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean that it did not work? Otherwise, I don't see why it would be unfortunate. However, if it didn't work, it would be helpful to say what happened. (And did you look at the documentation of `memoir` to figure out what it uses on the first page of chapters? `plain` is just an example from the standard classes.)

Comment: Note that using `geometry` rides roughshod over all the effort `memoir` puts into laying out your pages nicely!

Comment: OK. I'm also confused. In the code you posted, the table is just a table. It is not part of your header. You have separate headers which include the page number and graphic etc. But the table you define is just part of the document. Also, that is on the first page. So is the table not part of the header? Is it that you want that and the header on the first page and then just the header? Or...?

Comment: Well I am using geometry to make the text centered. If I do not use geometry the text has different white space to the right and to the left depending if the pages are odd or even. By modifying `\makepagestyle{mystyle}` to `\makepagestyle{plain}` has no effect on my output.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I do not know how to add the table on the header. I know how to create the table, but I do not know how to add it on the header and make it repeat on each page, including the first page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19187/discussion-between-thanos-and-cfr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the scheme: the table is inserted as the center field in the header, as a zero width box. For having it in all pages, use

```
\aliaspagestyle{plain}{mystyle}
```

so `memoir` will use `mystyle` also in the pages where `plain` is requested. The head height can be set after compiling once and looking in the `.log` file for a message such as

```
Class memoir Warning: The material used in the headers is too large
(73.19998pt) for the given head height (50.0pt), it is recommended to
either increase the head height or redesign the header
(in both cases you will find help in the memoir manual).
```

Here's the code. Note that the whole header is a single `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[a4paper,centering,headheight=75pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo option just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum} % demo option just for text
\usepackage{lastpage} % include last page numbering
\usepackage{chngpage} % allows for temporary adjustment of side margins
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY}}

\makepagestyle{mystyle}
\makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\thanoshead}{}
\makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\thanoshead}{}

\newcommand{\thanoshead}{%
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\includegraphics[height=20pt]{LOGO}} &
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}Informational\\USER GUIDE\end{tabular}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\thepage(\pageref{LastPage})} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\small\textbf{Prepared (subject responsible)}} &
      \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\small\textbf{No.}} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Thanos 1 \& Thanos 2} &
      \multicolumn{3}{l|}{1553-CXC1328930} \\
    \hline
    \small\textbf{Approved (Document responsible)} & &
    \small\textbf{Checked} & \small\textbf{Date} &
      \small\textbf{Rev.} & \small\textbf{Reference} \\
    & & & \mydate\today & J & Thanos\_UserGuide.tex \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\pagestyle{mystyle}
\aliaspagestyle{plain}{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this with `book` since you are overriding `memoir`'s page layout anyway and it is simpler to do it without needing to define tripartite headers.

I use `fancyhdr` to configure the header. I read the output to figure out what the header height needed to be so that I could feed this to `geometry`.

Since you want the header on every page, I've just redefined the `plain` style and used that. I used `demo` mode since I don't have your logo file, and I tidied up the table a bit.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[centering, headheight=80pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo option just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum} % demo option just for text
\usepackage{lastpage} % include last page numbering
\usepackage{datetime,array,fancyhdr}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\THEYEAR-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\twodigit{\THEDAY}}

\newsavebox{\mytabularheader}
\newsavebox{\mytabularheadertitle}
\sbox{\mytabularheadertitle}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.175\textwidth}
    Informational\\USER GUIDE
  \end{minipage}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhf[ch]{\usebox{\mytabularheader}}}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\sbox{\mytabularheader}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{>{\small}l|}}
      \multicolumn{3}{l}{\includegraphics[height=20pt]{example-image-a}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\usebox{\mytabularheadertitle}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\thepage(\pageref{LastPage})}\\[.25em]
      \hline
      \multicolumn{3}{|>{\small}l}{\textbf{Prepared (subject responsible)}} & \multicolumn{3}{|>{\small}l|}{\textbf{No.}} \\
      \multicolumn{3}{|>{\small}l}{Thanos 1 \& Thanos 2} & \multicolumn{3}{|>{\small}l|}{1553-CXC1328930} \\ \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{|>{\small}l|}{\textbf{Approved (Document responsible)}}  & \textbf{Checked} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Rev.} & \textbf{Reference} \\
      \multicolumn{2}{|>{\small}l|}{} &  & \mydate\today & J & Thanos\_UserGuide.tex \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}}

  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables

  \lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular pages]

Comment: Really nice answer, as a possible alternative. I will keep this in mind in case that I will use an alternative class than memoir. Again thank you for your time and effort.