# How do I add a table as a Header for every page?

Tags: tables, header-footer

I want to add a table as headers to all the pages (except title page) in my document.
I tried this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%...
\chead{
    \begin{tabular}{l|r}
        Lorem&Ipsum
    \end{tabular}
}
```

But it did not work.
How should I get it done?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215450/how-to-insert-a-table-on-the-header

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Which documentclass are you using?  It would be good to extend your code to be a minimal document we can compile for testing purposes (cf. [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2):

Add `\pagestyle{fancy}`

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
%...
\chead{
    \begin{tabular}{l|r}
        Lorem&Ipsum\\
        Lorem&Ipsum
    \end{tabular}
}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
```

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

```
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My title}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\clearpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the table now but there is an extra horizontal rule by the fancy pagestyle. Edit: [Got it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/how-to-remove-the-top-horizontal-bar-in-fancyhdr)

Comment: @BBloggsbott `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` or `\renewcommand{\headrule}{}`